How to hide a field on the frontend of a Buddypress page by field ID according to user roles and login status?
Not sure if this is the right place to post this or if I should use stack overflow. I can post it elsewhere if needed.
I am not a developer. I have very basic understanding of CSS classes (which is preceded by a dot), ID (preceded by a hash symbol), php (needing to be in single quotes) and HTML. I can paste CSS and PHP in the corresponding places in Wordpress (CSS: Appearances-> Customise -> scroll to the bottom of the left hand column and add custom CSS. PHP I use Code Snippet plugin or I can access the host's control panel and add it to the relevant PHP file, if someone tells me what it is called and where it could be). I can also use the "Inspect" tool in browsers.
I am creating a website with Wordpress and Buddypress and it will have a membership directory feature. I want to hide part of people's profiles, namely their contact details, specifically their phone numbers and email addresses, so that it is not visible to logged out viewers for obvious reasons, but also that only users with certain user roles (let's say as an example, "subscriber") can see it after logging in. I also want to display a message in their place to all logged out users and all logged in users that are not "subscriber" user roles, telling them that they cannot see it unless they become a "subscriber". Just to be very clear (because I've been seeing solutions for restricting the ability for users to see and edit those fields): I want to hide whatever the site member puts in those fields so a logged out visitor cannot see it, not limit the site member from seeing the field when they log in and want to edit their profile. For example, if a site member puts in their profile in the phone number field "1234", then a visitor to that profile page should not be able to see "1234" (ideally they'd see a message saying log in or sign up as "subscriber" to see their phone number" (or whatever that field is for). The only way for them to see it is if they become a site member with the user role "subscriber".
I used Bing AI Chat to get a plugin template to that is supposed to achieve the part where the fields containing contact information are hidden to users that are logged out. I opened a page containing the field I want to hide to visitors while logged out, right clicked on the field in the front end and selected "Inspect" and took the field number from that, it was in the form "field_22" or whatever other number the field is. Then I pasted the PHP code into the Code Snippet plugin, added the field numbers I wanted to hide and the user roles I want to allow ('subscriber' and 'administrator'), and activated it.
Here is the original code from Bing AI Chat:
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Profile Fields Visibility
 * Description: Hide specific profile fields for logged-out users and show them for specific user roles.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Your Name
 */

// Hook into the profile field visibility logic
add_filter('bp_xprofile_get_hidden_fields_for_user', 'custom_hide_profile_fields', 10, 2);

function custom_hide_profile_fields($hidden_fields, $user_id) {
    // Define the field IDs you want to hide
    $fields_to_hide = array(
        // Add field IDs here (e.g., 'field_1', 'field_2')
        // You can find the field IDs in the BuddyPress admin area
    );

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Get the user's role(s)
        $user_roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

        // Define the allowed user roles (customize as needed)
        $allowed_roles = array('subscriber', 'contributor'); // Example roles

        // Check if the user has an allowed role
        foreach ($user_roles as $role) {
            if (in_array($role, $allowed_roles)) {
                // Show the hidden fields for allowed roles
                return array_diff($hidden_fields, $fields_to_hide);
            }
        }
    }

    // Hide the fields for logged-out users and other roles
    return array_merge($hidden_fields, $fields_to_hide);
}


Here is the code after I put my field numbers in it:
Note: as I said, I am not a developer and I do not know if I put them in the correct places, or even if it is typed in the correct format. The fields I tried to hide were field_22 and field_23.
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Profile Fields Visibility
 * Description: Hide specific profile fields for logged-out users and show them for specific user roles.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Your Name
 */

// Hook into the profile field visibility logic
add_filter('bp_xprofile_get_hidden_fields_for_user', 'custom_hide_profile_fields', 22,23);

function custom_hide_profile_fields($hidden_fields, $user_id) {
    // Define the field IDs you want to hide
    $fields_to_hide = array('field_22', 'field_23'
        // Add field IDs here (e.g., 'field_22', 'field_23')
        // You can find the field IDs in the BuddyPress admin area
    );

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Get the user's role(s)
        $user_roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

        // Define the allowed user roles (customize as needed)
        $allowed_roles = array('subscriber', 'administrator'); // Example roles

        // Check if the user has an allowed role
        foreach ($user_roles as $role) {
            if (in_array($role, $allowed_roles)) {
                // Show the hidden fields for allowed roles
                return array_diff($hidden_fields, $fields_to_hide);
            }
        }
    }

    // Hide the fields for logged-out users and other roles
    return array_merge($hidden_fields, $fields_to_hide);
}


My question/issue:
When I run this code, every field on the profile page is gone when viewing it logged out or if logged in as a not-allowed user role, not just the field I specified. If logged in as an allowed role, everything is visible.

What can I do to make it so that only the specified fields (ie field_22 and field_23) are hidden from view when logged out or logged in as a not-allowed role, rather than the entire profile? Note that Buddypress profiles are not Wordpress pages so it's not like I can open and edit one and place shortcode on it.

In the very first line of actual code (not the comments), right after the comment "// Hook into the profile field visibility logic", at the end, you can see that I changed the numbers 10 and 2 to 22 and 23 because I thought I have to put the field numbers there. Not sure if this makes a difference. I also tested it with 10 and 2 and there was no difference, everything or nothing was hidden depending on log in and user role status. But what I noticed is that if I remove those two numbers entirely, regardless of what numbers they actually are, on the front end of that page, I get a "critical error" notice on the page. The rest of the site is fine.

If I can fix the issue of the fields not hiding properly, then my next question is, how can I add a message in place of the hidden fields telling the user to log in or register as an allowed user role?


Thank you very much.
